# What is Buffer Underrun?

Tags: buffer

Just what the title states - What does Buffer Underrun mean?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_underrun

Comment: Indeed. I think the question is not unambiguous, vague, overly broad or incomplete and it can very reasonably be answered, as Matti proved.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's when a buffer that's being read from (and should preferably always have data available) runs empty.

An audio output device is a good example. An audio device will read its buffer at a constant rate, and unless you keep supplying it data at a fast enough rate, the buffer will run out. And it'll sound nasty.